# Returns an array of all defined variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, token, server

I'm trying to get ALL php defined variables into an array.

I was trying :

```
$myArr = get_defined_vars();
var_dump($myArr);
```

Result :

```
array(4) { ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_COOKIE"]=> array(0) { } ["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } }
```

BUT I'm expecting to get ALL php defined variables :

```
_SERVER["MIBDIRS"]    
_SERVER["MYSQL_HOME"]    
_SERVER["OPENSSL_CONF"]    
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"]    
_SERVER["PHPRC"]
_SERVER["TMP"]    
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]   
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]    
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]    
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]    
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]    
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  
_SERVER["PATH"]    
_SERVER["SystemRoot"]    
_SERVER["COMSPEC"]    
_SERVER["PATHEXT"]   
_SERVER["WINDIR"]    
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]    
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]    
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]   
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]    
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]   
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]   
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    
_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]    
_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]    
_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"]    
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]    
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]    
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]    
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]    
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]    
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]    
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]    
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]    
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]    
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]    
$_POST   
$_GET   
$_FILES    
$_SERVER    
$_REQUEST    
$_SESSION    
$_COOKIE   
$_ENV    
$GLOBALS    
$argc    
$argv    
$this    
$php_errormsg    
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS    
$HTTP_POST_VARS   
$HTTP_POST_FILES    
//etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with `get_defined_vars()` or any other SPL functions to my knowledge. You should check `$_SERVER` and others manually. Also, normally you wouldn't want all those variables you listed, some of them are deprecated or equivalent of each other.

Comment: I believe having `$_SERVER` in `get_defined_vars()` was a feature with older versions of PHP only, deprecated in v5.3, removed since v5.4.

Comment: You can't mark a question "impossible". Just leave it there for others with the same problem later and if there'll ever be a solution, someone will write you the correct answer. (but tbh in the last 7 years of my PHP career I never needed something like that, should be something of a really bad design)

Comment: OK I WANT TO CLARIFY... I'M TRYING TO MAKE PHP VARIABLES Obfuscator SO I DON'T WANT TO TOUCH ALL DEFINED PHP VARIABLES... HOPE IT MAKES MORE SCENE NOW... THANKS !

Comment: You won't be able to obfuscate superglobals anyways. Only if you create new variables for all of them. Have you tried Zend Obfuscator?

Comment: @Rápli András I want to create my own php obfuscator so I can sell it :)

Comment: @iprophesy Well, good luck with that. Just to mention, today I've had my whole project refactored to follow PSR-4 standards. I'm an anti-obfuscator freak.